# Dereferenced pointer to vector element has extra digit in front after being shifted

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, element

I am using a pointer to vector elements to step through and access vector elements, but if I try cout << *(ptr - 1); , I get a 9 in front of the correct number. For example, if we have:

```
vector<uint> v{1,2,3};
uint *ptr = &v[0];
ptr++;
cout << *(ptr - 1);
```

I would get 91 instead of 1. Similarly if I put:

```
cout << *(ptr - 2);
```

I get 81 instead of 1. I want to compare v[i-1] to v[i] using pointers but I keep getting that extra digit in front of v[i-1] through the dereferenced pointer. I have tried assigning a new pointer `uint *ptr2; ptr2 = ptr; ptr++; cout << ptr2;` but I have the same issue.

EDIT: here is the full source code:

```
void bucketSort(vector<uint>& v, uint numDigits)
{
    const uint v_size = v.size();
    
    // vector< vector<uint> > bucket;
    // bucket.resize(10, vector<uint>(v_size));
    //auto starti = chrono::system_clock::now();
    //uint bucket[10][v_size];
    uint **bucket = new uint*[10];
    for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
    {
        bucket[m] = new uint[v_size];
    }

    uint *bval = &bucket[0][0];

    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < v_size; m++)
        {
            *bval = UINT_MAX;
            bval++;
        }
    }
    // auto stopi = chrono::system_clock::now();
    // cout << "Initialize: "
    // << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(stopi-starti).count()
    // << "ms" << endl;

    uint num, b_size, temp, pnum;
    uint *val;
    int ind, flag;
    
    for (uint d = 0; d < numDigits; d++)
    {
        ind = 0;
        flag = 0;
        //auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
        val = v.data();
        bval = &bucket[0][0];
        for (uint i = 0; i < v_size; i++)
        {
            temp = *val;
   
            for (int b = 0; b <= d; b++)
            {
                num = temp % 10;
                temp = temp/10;
            }
            bval += (num*v_size) + i;
            *bval = *val;
            val++;
            if (*(val - 1) > *val)
            {
                cout << *(val - 1) << ", " << *val << endl; <----- problem
                flag = 1;
            }
            //pval++;
            bval = &bucket[0][0];  
        }
        if(flag == 0){break;}
...
```

Comment: What does the C language have to do with this question?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @eerorika i tried doing that in another program, as the one i am referencing here is pretty long, but it worked fine in the new program. Do you mind if i post the original code? its about 80 lines

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the contents of the vector as an array, use the [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member function to get a pointer to it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
 
int main() {
    std::vector<uint> v = {1,2,3};
    uint *ptr = v.data();
    ptr++;
    std::cout << *(ptr-1);
 
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/OhviQn)

In `bucketsort()` you're misusing `bval`. You can't keep incrementing it to get to different rows in the 2-dimensional array, because the rows are not contiguous. Change the loop that fills in `bucket` to:

```
    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)
    {
        uint *bval = bucket[i];
        for (int m = 0; m < v_size; m++)
        {
            *bval = UINT_MAX;
            bval++;
        }
    }
```

I don't really understand the other loop that uses `bucket`, but it needs to be similar.

Comment: Just tried this, still getting the 9 in front

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I added a link to an online demo.

Comment: thank you, I included my source code if that helps you reproduce the problem. I used the v.data() method in my test code and it works fine but it produces the same problem when I try it in my original program, so i think I am doing something incorrect with my pointer somewhere.

Comment: The loop with `*bval = UINT_MAX;` doesn't look right. It's assuming that all the elements of `bucket` are contiguous.

Comment: Why are you trying to do so many things with pointers instead of array indexing? Use `bucket[l][m] = UINT_MAX;`

Comment: Your method would work if it were `uint bucket[10][v_size]`, but not when `bucket` is an array of pointers.

Comment: array indexing is slower, i have been trying to improve code speed

Comment: Or you could do `uint *bucket = new uint[10 * v_size];`

Comment: I tried those variations of declaring bucket, but the problem persists. Under further investigation, the *(val - 1) is outputting 999990 if v[0] = 0 and 999991 if v[1] = 1, etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the correct way to iterate through `bucket`.